# Unable to add roles to SimpleMembership foreign key error on webpages_Roles

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "fk_RoleId". The conflict occurred in database "mydb", table "dbo.webpages_Roles", column 'RoleId'.

I'm not sure what is causing this issue, I've gone to `dbo.webpages_UsersInRoles` and removed the FK constraints and it still comes down to this error. Not sure what to do here.

```
WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.RegistrationInfo.UserName, model.RegistrationInfo.Password);

Roles.AddUserToRole(model.RegistrationInfo.UserName, level); //both strings
```

Adding them the right way but the database just won't accept these entries. here is the db schemas.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[webpages_Roles] (
    [RoleId]   INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [RoleName] NVARCHAR (256) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED ([RoleId] ASC),
    UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([RoleName] ASC)
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[webpages_UsersInRoles] (
    [RoleId] INT NOT NULL,
    [UserId] INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_webpages_UsersInRoles] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([RoleId] ASC, [UserId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_webpages_UsersInRoles_UserProfile] FOREIGN KEY ([UserId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[UserProfile] ([UserId]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_webpages_UsersInRoles_webpages_Roles] FOREIGN KEY ([RoleId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[webpages_Roles]([RoleId])
);
```

I'm only able to manually entering integers as roleid and userid pairs.

I've seen this issue on other people's posts but no solution was to be found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you already have that role in your database. I think in your database that role isn't exists in webpages_roles table. That's why this problem occurred.

```
if (!Roles.RoleExists(newRoleName)) {
    Roles.CreateRole(newRoleName) 
};
```

You should do this before you assign roles.

Comment: True, that is the correct way to use the API, but role non-existence is not of concern (its confirmed its there)

Answer (score 1):

Swap order of UserId and RoleId in webpages_UsersInRoles table. UserId shall be the first column.